# Pyautogui doesn't work in windows task scheduler

Tags: python, pyautogui, windows-task-scheduler

I wrote a script to handle the mouse and keyboard to help me deal with the works in windows by using the library "Pyautogui".

it went well if it was in a logging active session, but it doesn't work if the windows went to lock screen.
I can't disable the lock screen because of the security issue.

Comment: Last I call recall that's by design (but I haven't worked with Windows in a while).